# Book Reccomendation to learn measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to know if there are any 'accessible' books to understand measure theory. I came across videos of Jay Cummings on YouTube channel 'The Bright Side of Mathematics' (if anyone knows that) and fould almost everything I was looking for, except for the fact that I couldn't truly get through the first videos until sigma algebras are introduced. I cannot picture in my mind any understandable example, what basics I am missing not to be able to understand them? I have been through some abstract algebra but that didn't help, except for the formalism.

Comment: This should be asked on math.stackexchange

Comment: Surely the most understandable example is a finite set, then the integers, then the real number line, then the plane. After that, I don't know any examples of measure spaces which are different from these in an interesting way, and I don't remember meeting any in a first measure theory course.

Answer (score 3):

Halmos, Paul R. Measure Theory. D. Van Nostrand Co., Inc., New York, 1950. xi+304 pp.

Malliavin, P. Intégration et probabilités. Analyse de Fourier et analyse spectrale, Masson, Paris, 1982. 200 pp.

Kadets, Vladimir A course in functional analysis and measure theory, Universitext. Springer, Cham, 2018.

Tao, Terence An introduction to measure theory. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 126. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2011.